# Will a 11-speed cassette fit my Giant SRC 3 frame (~2007)

Tags: road-bike, frames, cassette, 1x11

I would like to upgrade an older Giant SRC 3 (~2007). Having a very limited experience with bike mechanics, how will i find out whether a 11-speed cassette will fit the frame and or the wheels?

Comment: The frame is not a problem, the hubs can be. But do not forget you need the complete new drivetrain. It is probably better to buy a new bike from the financial point of view.

Comment: What hub do you have in the rear wheel?   8/9/10 speed cassettes are all the same width.  But an 11 speed cassette is wider and also intended to "overlap" dead parts of the hub.  So it really matters more what the hub is.   You'll also need new chain/shifter/derailleur at a minimum.

Comment: @Criggie The cassette is an 8-speed SRAM. Nothing written on the hub, but it's a HG type. The flat "ribs" are ~33.5 mm long.

Comment: The Shimano 11/34 11sp is designed to fit 10 speed bodies because the hole in the center of the 34 is large.  That can save you a new wheel, but I don't like the 11/13/15 spacing at the top end.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are planning to upgrade the older frame to a newer complete 11 speed groupset. Makes sense as 105 rim brake groups are relatively inexpensive now.

In 2007 11 speed road groupsets didn’t exit, so we can assume your Giant had a 10, 9 speed or less groupset, and a 10 speed or less compatible hub.

When 11 speed groups were introduced the width of the splined free hub body on the hub was made a little wider to accommodate an extra sprocket. This means 11 speed cassettes will not fit on your hub, so you need new wheels with an 11 speed free hub body.

However, some wider range cassettes can overhang the inboard end of the free hub a little and will fit on a 10 speed hub (a spacer is used on an 11 speed hub), but of course you need a long cage derailleur to work with the wide range cassette.

FYI, frame dropout spacing didn’t need to get wider for 11 speed groups, still 130mm for rim brake setups.

Answer (score 0):

A 11 speed freehub should be 36.75mm deep. That's 1.8mm wider than a 8/9/10 speed freehub.  I think that's measured to the upstand, not to the end of the rib.

8/9/10 speed cassettes are all the same width and should be interchangeable on the same hub.

So given you have an 8 speed cassette now, your cheapest upgrade path is to go to 10 speed, which should simply fit onto the existing hub.   You will need a new shifter with 9 clicks (10 positions)   and maybe a new derailleur.  Also will need a new 10speed chain.

Personally I'd recommend new gear inner/outer cable too - they're cheap and now's the time.

There is a chance an 11 speed cassette will fit, but you'd have to get one and try it first.  The lockring has to thread in by multiple turns to be secure.   If you can borrow an 11 speed cassette, that might be safest.  Or buy one on the understanding it can be returned if it doesn't fit.